# How to copy a specific field from a list of any classes in JAVA?

Tags: java

Let's me start describe my problem.

I have a class, Person, which is stored in mPeople List. 
So it does mean that the mPeople will store both "name" and "age".
But in a certain circumstance, I need a list of all people's name and a list of all people's age in different List.

So is there a way to copy all the data in a specific field of a class in a list to another list or somewhere else?

*Note: I know i can use for loop or enhance for loop to do this but it does not look so good through this. So just curious if someone found any better solutions... And I would appreciate your help!*

```
public class Person
{

 // fields
    private int age;
    private String name;


    // constructor
    public Person( int age, String name )
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }


    // getter
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}


//list of People
List<Person> mPeople = new ArrayList<>();
mPeople.add( new Person( 10, "Sovanara" ) );
mPeople.add( new Person( 20, "Dara" ) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can map over the stream:

```
final List<String> names = mPeople.stream()
    .map( it -> it.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

final List<Integer> ages= mPeople.stream()
    .mapToInt( it -> it.getAge())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm doing this as two passes here to show you what they each look like. You could do these as a side effect in a `forEach` if you'd rather do one pass. For large sets of people that might be worth thinking about, if you are tight on resources.

**Edit**: Single pass solution (which depends on side effects):

```
final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<>();
mPeople.stream().forEach({ it -> 
    names.add(it.getName());
    ages.add(it.getAge());
});
```

Since you also tagged this as Kotlin, the solutions are similar:

```
val names = mPeople.map { it.name }
val ages = mPeople.map { it.age }
```

Comment: I see. By the way, you mention side-effect of foreach. Did it mean, it would be better to use one pass rather than many passes or many time of operation? I just one to make sure.

Comment: It depends. I personally find two passes easier to understand and follow. However, a single pass is more efficient. If you have a small list of People, it really won't make much difference, only optimize if you have to. I tend to err on the side of making the code readable at the expense of a bit of performance, if it's not critical.

Comment: i checked it out and found out that you don't have to convert it to list using .toList(). Seems like Kotlin does it all.. and lastly, thank for a nice solutions and advises.!

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to use streams.

A quick example could look something like this:

```
List<Integer> mAges = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
mPeople.stream().forEach(p->{mAges.add(p.getAge());
                             mNames.add(p.getName());
                             }
                         );
```

Of course you would need to be using the right version of java. 
Just for fun I thought I would add a few ways to do it without streams, although I would prefer to use streams in this case.

Probably the most basic way:

```
for(int i =0; i < mPeople.size();i++){
   mAges.add(mPeople.get(i).getAge());
   mNames.add(mPeople.get(i).getName());
}
```

Another way:

```
for(Person p: mPeople){
   mAges.add(p.getAge());
   mNames.add(p.getName());
}
```